# Running Python on a webserver using PHP

Tags: python, php

I am using a PHP script to run a python script on a localhost xampp webserver:

```
<?php
$python_path = 'C:\Users\alona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe';
$output = shell_exec($python_path . ' my_script.py');
echo $output;
?>
```

If the python script contains `print("Hi")` for example, The PHP code runs the python program and displays the output like so:

```
echo $output;
```

And it works fine, it shows "Hi"

However, when the python file contains a more complex python code:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

city = input("What country do you live in? ")
timezone = pytz.timezone(city)

current_time = datetime.now(timezone)
print("The time in your country is:", current_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

The php page shows just "What's your country" And it does not let the user write his country and display the second output. The PHP script needs to work like a command line, but on a web page.
So if on my computer, i use:
python my_script.py
The program asks:
What country do you live in?
Canada
The time in your country is: 09:52:06
The same should work on my PHP script.

Comment: It'll be halting on the `input(...` bit, waiting for a human to type something in. But there's no human there, only PHP, which has no way of interacting with the script once it's running. Adapt the python script to take the input value(s) on the command-line instead, so it can run fully automated, and PHP can pass in any necessary value(s) in the shell_exec string.

Comment: You should be able to run anything that doesn't involve user interaction during the python code. The moment that happens, you're stuck because a) php has no way to interact with the script once it's executing, and b) there is no way to capture input direct from a user at that moment either, because you're halfway through a http request at that point, the script is running on the server and the user is sat on their browser on a different machine waiting for it to complete. You can't just expect all code written for one kind of environment to work perfectly in another.

Comment: Can I make that work on a webpage in a different language? Maybe with HTML or javascript?

Comment: Html is just a markup language for displaying data. Javascript, if you mean the sort running in a browser, can certainly interact with the user but it can't execute python...it would have to send a http request to a server to run a script, at which point you're back in the same situation again. Python itself can also be directly invoked by a webserver in the same way as php btw so you can cut out the middleman, but of course you'd still have to refactor your scripts. The web and command line work in very different ways and apps have to be designed differently - that's the reality.